# Applying a function in parallel to pandas Series made of objects, why returns NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, vectorization

To understand my problem, I should first explain a bit the object structure called Animal.

My object has 3 fields:
-obj.a = an integer
-obj.b = a dictionary
`obj.b = {'x':x1, 'y':x2, ....}`
-obj.c = a dictionary of dictionaries
`obj.c = {'x': {'x1':a1, ..., 'xn': an}, ... , 'y': {'y1':a1, ..., 'yn': an}`

What I have is a pandas series of objects of type Animal called 'animal'.
I then have a function that computes this:

```
def foo(x: Animal):
    try:
        return x.a + (x.b['y'] + 2* x.c['x']['x1'])
    except:
        return np.nan
```

How can i make as fast as possible somthing like:
`df['value'] = foo(df['animal'])`

For now i am doing this:

`df['value'] = df['animal'].apply(foo)`

But i think it can be vectorized.

Does anyone have a quicker solution than this?

Answer (score 1):

`apply` takes a function. `foo` is a function. You don't need to create a function with `apply(lambda x: foo(x))`, you can just do `apply(foo)`.

You should also be able to do `vec_foo = np.vectorize(foo)` and then `df['value'] = vec_foo(df['animal'])`.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited it but I still wonder if it can be done in some way using vectorization.